# Как правильно обрабатывать ошибки при использовании Async/Await?

Tags: javascript

Допустим метод который пишет в базу redis:

```
getError(){
        return this.error;
}

setValue = (key,data) =>{
        this.error = null;
        return new Promise(resolve =>{
            connect.set(key, data,(err, reply) =>{
                this.error = err;
                resolve(reply);
            });
        });
};
```

После вызова `setValue()`, я могу проверить ошибки запроса вызвав `getError()`. Но такой подход мне не кажется хорошим.
Есть варианты более корректной обработки ошибок?

Comment: Можно передавать в конструктор `Promise` не функцию, принимающую один аргумент (`resolve`), а функцию, принимающую два аргумента (`resolve`, `reject`). Внутри функции в случае ошибки вызывать `reject` вместо `resolve`, а снаружи обрабатывать ошибки через `try..catch`.

Comment: @diraria А как бы это все удобнее писать чтобы снаружи не оборачивать в try/catch? Я к тому что если мне необходимо сделать несколько запросов в одном методе, и если после каждого городить конструкцию try/catch - будет много кода. В этом случае, можно ли как-то чтобы при вызове `reject` вызывался какой-то метод снаружи выводящий ошибку и при этом завершал работу текущего? Или я это я уже фигни напридумывал?

Comment: Можно вообще ничего не оборачивать, тогда при возникновении ошибки весь текущий код перестанет выполняться, и в консоли выведется ошибка. Можно обернуть твой метод, тогда при возникновении ошибки в любом из запросов, ошибка пробросится выше и будет поймана твоим `try..catch`.